# Search option in Android Location and Map

Tags: android, google-maps

Hiii...m making an applcation in which i have implemented google map..m able to call current location of mine in my app..now i have following queries:

1)I want to add search option in my map..with that search option i can find places and things.

2)how will i navigate from my current location to the destination which i will select from my search result..

3) want to place marker to my current location.and want to autozoom to my current location

m not getting any idea:(.can anybody help me to solve this??

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.navigate;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


   private GoogleMap googleMap;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


               googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
               findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


         googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

3) want to place marker to my current location.and want to autozoom to my current location

answer:-  this is what how you will get current location
[current location in google map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26099142/2702583)

-> this is for marker on your current location

```
      markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
      markerOptions.position(new LatLng (latitude, longitude) );
      markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
      googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);`
```